# How to get Total SUM based on WHEREclause that contain NULL's

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have  table `PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet` that have column WrittenPremium and SICCode. Column SICCode has `NULL` values.
 The Sum of total `WrittenPremium` is 108,515,689.

So if I say:

```
select sum(WrittenPremium) 
from PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet
```

The result is correct.

But if I say

```
  select sum(WrittenPremium) 
    from PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet
WHERE SICCode IN ('0161','0173','0179','0181'...)
```

The result is 108,024,995 which is incorrect, because it doesn't pick up `SICCode` that have `NULL` value.

I tried use ISNULL function, but still no success:

```
   select sum(WrittenPremium) 
        from PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet
    WHERE ISNULL(SICCode,0) IN ('0161','0173','0179','0181'...)
```

So how would I get the whole `sum` of `WrittenPremium` using `where` clause?

Comment: So you used `IsNull` to substitute a value of `0` for NULLs, but if `0` isn't one of the choices on the right side of the `IN` it won't help. And if `0` is a valid `SICCode` then things get more confusing. It's also not exactly a best practice to mix datatypes by supplying a default `INT` value to be tested against a collection of strings.

Comment: Your query says `WHERE ISNULL(SICCode,0) IN ('0161',...` - two questions, why are you mixing strings and integers, and why didn't you include `0` in the right-hand side of the `IN()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE SICCode IN ('0161','0173','0179','0181'...) 
   OR SICCode is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

select sum(WrittenPremium) 
        from PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet
    WHERE ISNULL(SICCode,0) IN ('0','0161','0173','0179','0181'...)

Regards

Abdul

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the value in a coalesce.

select sum(coalesce(WrittenPremium,0)) 
        from PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet
    WHERE ISNULL(SICCode,0) IN ('0161','0173','0179','0181'...)

Comment: I tried that. It described in the question. Doesnt work.